# Android Emulator not starting in a Virtualbox Ubuntu Instance

Tags: android, eclipse, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using Windows 7 64-bit (12 GB of RAM), with VirtualBox 4.2.4 running an instance of Linux Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit.

My Ubuntu VM has 128MB of Video Memory, 3D Acceleration, 4GB of RAM, 2 CPU processors, and ample space.

I installed Eclipse Juno in my VirtualBox instance, downloaded the Android SDK from http://developers.android.com.

I set up my AVD to be running Android 4.2, with an API level of 17 using an ARM CPU.

In Eclipse, I created a new Android application (a basic application) and tried to run it. The emulator never loads up, though.

I get variations of the following error when trying to launch:

```
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x9dbb250, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x9dbb328
```

I did some research on the XGetVisualInfo, and it appears to be VirtualBox related. Can any one provide a pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that for two reasons: the emulator use the Intel Virtualization Technology (VT) or the AMD Virtualization (AMD) extension but this is already used by the Ubuntu VM running inside the VirtualBox and you cannot use that a second time inside an already running VM.

There is also the same thing for a CPU interrupt related to debugging/interrupting the VM that is also already used by the VirtualBox and that cannot be shared a second time by another embedded VM but I don't remember the exact detail about this one.

I don't know your reasons of running the emulator inside a VM but one thing you can do is to run the emulator directly inside the VirtualBox as its own VM or outside of VirtualBox and etablish a connection between Eclipse and the emulator.  On the web, you will find many references on how to run an emulator directly inside VirtualBox.  I have done it myself in the past and there were no problem.

Comment: Thank you for providing a detailed explanation of what is going on! I had a feeling that this might be related to the fact that my resources were already allocated.

Comment: "I don't know your reasons of running the emulator inside a VM"
I develop all my software projects each in it's own VM.